# How to query from nested SELECT using SQLAlchemy ORM

Tags: python, mysql, sql, python-3.x, sqlalchemy

***Edit***: This was correctly marked as duplicate. Sorry and thank you for the answer.

I'm trying to write the query below using SQLAlchemy.

```
SELECT CODE, SECTOR, AVG(ITEMS), WEEKDAY(DATE)

FROM(
    SELECT CODE, SECTOR, DATE, SUM(ITEMS) AS ITEMS
    FROM sales
    GROUP BY CODE, SECTOR, DATE
) AS aggregate

WHERE DATE >= '2019-02-01'
AND DATE <= '2019-04-30'
GROUP BY CODE, SECTOR, WEEKDAY(DATE)
```

I already have an auto-mapped sales table named `tSales`. I can write the inner SELECT like this:

```
aggregate = (session
    .query(tSales.CODE,
        tSales.SECTOR,
        tSales.DATE,
        func.sum(tSales.ITEMS).label('ITEMS'))
    .group_by(tSales.CODE, tSales.SECTOR, tSales.DATE)
    .all())
```

My question is: in this case, **how can I query from a nested SELECT**?

Thank you for the attention.